# Using IN with a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column, called `c_arr`, which value is `('a', 'b', 'c')`
And I have a variable in php. And I would like to check, if the variable is in the array.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '${str}' IN c_arr
```

It doesn't works for some reason. What should I do, to make it work?

Comment: Normalize your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) instead of `IN`.

But you should really consider normalizing your data and put `c_arr` in a separate table with a foreign key to your table above.